# Javascript object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

I have below piece of code where I am fetching some data from mongodb and printing it on console:

```
var data=await model.find({TRACK:"ABC"});
console.log(data);
data.forEach(elem=>{
  console.log(elem.prop1);
  console.log(elem.prop2);
});
```

`data` contains below array:

```
[{TRACK:"ABC",prop1:"ghj",prop2:"tyu"},
{TRACK:"ABC",prop1:"jkl",prop2:"vbn"}]
```

The problem is that inside `forEach` loop, the value of `prop1` is getting printed but the value of `prop2` is undefined, even if `prop2` is available in the result data. I have also tried doing `elem["prop2"]`, but it is also giving `undefined` while `prop2` gives just fine result.

Can you help me to find the probable reason behind this?

Thank You!

Comment: Well, everything looks fine, I guess you should use *debugger* carefully to find out what's wrong. Maybe data is incomplete, maybe property name is misspelled maybe other wierd stuff. You don't know until you don't see.

Comment: is your second block of code what your console.log(data) has as an output? Because if it is this should be the outcome https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gFQEoCCAwgNIBcARAQEJEUA0ADgE4iMCMlA5gBYBWDFmwBMlKAE8ArhQC+9ALAAoXIVKUadJqw6U+AawA2g7aIoA3AEZhZAXSVLQkWADM08JAgB0zkMwCiCMA8ABQApgahALaoAHxYSjAwjhAgEZ4GIFxhEZGeQhwAlADcCUngKWkZWeFReSbFSjINig7lqaHpmcHOBUA

Comment: "_`data` contains below array_". It obviously doesn't. You can check the response data in Network tab of the DevTools.

Comment: Actually this code is in nodejs, so I can't actually use the browser dev console. If I print each object of the data array, it indeed shows prop2 and its respective value. But when I try to access it in the code, it is undefined.

Comment: @Kanojian https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```html
data = [
  { TRACK: 'ABC', prop1: 'ghj', prop2: 'tyu' },
  { TRACK: 'ABC', prop1: 'jkl', prop2: 'vbn' },
];

Object.entries(data).forEach((entry) => {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
});
```